# Android: geofence expiration

Tags: android, google-maps

Is there any way to trigger the Geofence expiration(e.g in a callback method)?
I would like to recalculate the path on my gps-tracker app only if a geofence has not been entered in a certain amount of time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just keep track of the entered events yourself. In each callback for a geofence tripped event you are given a Geofence Id and then you can perform your logic and remove/add the geofence(s) with the new expiration if needed.

Comment: Thx for answering. I have already set everything to trigger the entering or exiting. The problem is that I would like to be informed  if the geofence's expiration time has finished even if   no entering or exiting event has been triggered

Comment: You can still keep track of that yourself and set timers to alert you when a expiration time has hit. If that geofence has not been used in awhile, you can remove it. Nothing comes out of the box with the Geofence API. You'll have to build something yourself by keeping track of the data.