# Android how to know when Geofence has expired?

Tags: android, android-location, android-geofence

I have set the expiration duration of my Geofence using ***[setExpirationDuration()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/Geofence.Builder.html#public-methods)*** method. Now, how can I know when my Geofence has expired. Is there a callback or something?

I have seen this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26331403/android-geofence-expiration), but I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Just to get some context on this question, why are you wanting to know if a geofence has expired or not?  As for checking if your geofence has expired, have you checked if the Geofence list in the GeofencingRequest class to see if you geofence is still in the list?  According to the docs, once expired, a geofence is removed.

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no api support to get the expired geofences nor a list of geofences.

I see two options:

1. Would be to store the geofences (for example in SharedPreferences) and then each time you need to know if a geofence expired, just iterate through all the stored geofences.
2. Would be to schedule an intent when the geofence expired.

**Implementation for option 1)**

I suggest you to create a class that can be stored internally (in SharedPreferences for example):

```
public class MyGeofence {
    private String id;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    private float radiusMeters;
    private int transitionType;
    private long expirationDurationMillis;

    public Geofence buildGeofence() {
        return new Geofence.Builder()
                .setCircularRegion(latitude, longitude, radiusMeters)
                .setRequestId(id)
                .setExpirationDuration(expirationDurationMillis)
                .setTransitionTypes(transitionType)
                .build();
    }

    ...
}
```

So when you want to add a geofence you should first create an object of this class, call `buildGeofence`, add it using `LocationServices.GeofencingApi.addGeofences()` and then store it.

Then whenever you want to know which geofences expired, you should iterate all the stored MyGeofence objects.

**Implementation for option 2)**

When you set the expiration for your geofence you should also schedule a pendingIntent.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

long futureInMillis = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + delay;
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, futureInMillis, pendingIntent);
```

Remember to register in manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" />
```